# How to Move a View in Between RecyclerView and Relative Layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, move, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to develop a Jigsaw Puzzle for Android. I need to move items between the Pieces area `RecyclerView` and Draft of the Puzzle area `Relative Layout`.

So, players should be able to drag and drop pieces. I cannot figure out how to do it. All help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

As in this image:
[image]

Comment: This may help: https://sunny89blog.wordpress.com/2017/07/16/transfer-items-from-one-recyclerview-to-another-and-vice-versa/